# What is the most suitable icon for a "Purchase Document" button?

Tags: buttons, icons, shopping-cart, purchase

I am designing an interface for a legal document ordering system, and I want to use an icon for the ordering button, but I don't want it to be the standard shopping cart icon, as it's not really an online store with an actual cart. Each time they click this button it processes the purchase/order.

I am also hesitant to use a 'download' icon, because the user needs to understand that by clicking the button they will be charged a fee.

Comment: You could try different searches in [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) to see what can you get. The tags are quite well assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I would have the icon you use reinforce the messaging on the button. Since you are not adding items to a cart, a shopping cart icon wouldn't make sense.

I would have a button with the text "buy" or "purchase" or "buy and download" to set expectations of what will happen when that button is clicked. You could add a lock icon, a money symbol icon, a download icon or something along those lines. In your case, I would say the button text is more important than the icon you choose.

Comment: Thank you, that's a really good point! I think I will do that.